# Implementing a conv2d backward in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation

I want to implement backward function of conv2d.

Here is an [example of a linear function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html):

```py
# Inherit from Function
class LinearFunction(Function):

    @staticmethod
    # bias is an optional argument
    def forward(ctx, input, weight, bias=None):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input, weight, bias)
        output = input.mm(weight.t())
        if bias is not None:
            output += bias.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(output)
        return output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, weight, bias = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_input = grad_weight = grad_bias = None

        if ctx.needs_input_grad[0]:
            grad_input = grad_output.mm(weight)
        if ctx.needs_input_grad[1]:
            grad_weight = grad_output.t().mm(input)
        if bias is not None and ctx.needs_input_grad[2]:
            grad_bias = grad_output.sum(0)

        return grad_input, grad_weight, grad_bias
```

```py
class Linear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_features, output_features, bias=True):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.input_features = input_features
        self.output_features = output_features

        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.empty(output_features, input_features))
        if bias:
            self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.empty(output_features))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)

        # Not a very smart way to initialize weights
        nn.init.uniform_(self.weight, -0.1, 0.1)
        if self.bias is not None:
            nn.init.uniform_(self.bias, -0.1, 0.1)

    def forward(self, input):
        # See the autograd section for explanation of what happens here.
        return LinearFunction.apply(input, self.weight, self.bias)
```

I don't think I have a clear understanding of this function yet.

How can I implement conv2d backward function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation of the conv2d backward function:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Function
from torch.nn.modules.utils import _pair
from torch.nn import init

import math
import numpy as np

class Conv2dFunction(Function):

    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input, weight, bias=None, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1):
        output = F.conv2d(input, weight,  bias, stride, padding, dilation, groups)

        ctx.save_for_backward(input, weight, bias)
        ctx.stride = stride
        ctx.padding = padding 
        ctx.dilation = dilation
        ctx.groups = groups

        return output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):

        input, weight, bias = ctx.saved_tensors
        stride = ctx.stride
        padding = ctx.padding 
        dilation = ctx.dilation
        groups = ctx.groups
        grad_input = grad_weight = grad_bias = None

        if ctx.needs_input_grad[0]:
            grad_input = torch.nn.grad.conv2d_input(input.shape, weight, grad_output, stride, padding, dilation, groups)
        if ctx.needs_input_grad[1]:
            grad_weight = torch.nn.grad.conv2d_weight(input, weight.shape, grad_output, stride, padding, dilation, groups) 
        if bias is not None and ctx.needs_input_grad[2]:
            grad_bias = grad_output.sum((0,2,3)).squeeze(0)

        return grad_input, grad_weight, grad_bias, None, None, None, None
```

Comment: Tried this and currently hitting the following error: 
Legacy autograd function with non-static forward method is deprecated. Trying to find the problem here, because the code seems correct.